# Network Establishment Between Windows 7 and Windows XP

Tags: windows

How can I connect Windows 7 PC with Windows XP PC with only network cable?
I want to share drives with each other.

Answer (score 1):

1st, you cannot use a standard network cable, you will need what is called a cross over cable.

2nd, once you have done this and set proper permissions, you should be able to browse to that computer.

A good place to start would windows easy transfer.  More details here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Easy_Transfer

p.s. Welcome to stackoverflow  :)

Comment: but yet its not really needed with a standard cable also you can transfer data but speeds will be low

Comment: I am not sure, but assuming that he will also need to set the IP's manually on both computers as there won't be a DHCP. If so I would recommend you set them to 192.168.0.1 and 192.168.0.2.

Comment: @Nate: Welcome to the present, where MDI-X is common (hint: no crossover needed). @Fuji: Both machines will auto-IP (into 169.254.0.0/16), so static is not absolutely required.

Answer (score 0):

As Theatrus said, you may not require a special cable if your machines support Auto-MDI, however, if your machines don't, you will require a cross over cable.

After this, the easiest thing you can do is to run the Windows Network Wizard on both machines which should enable the default services for you.

You can then right click on drives/folders and share them.

However, If this is a one off task, you may have more luck using a direct USB to USB cable and Windows Easy Transfer.